# Is the CMC of a creature that is enchanted the cost of the enchantment and the creature combined?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Just started playing MTG and I have a [Filigree Familiar](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bFiligree%20Familiar%5d) of 3 cost enchanted with [Marked by Honor](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMarked%20by%20Honor%5d) with a cost of 4. Does the CMC of the Filigree Familiar equal 3 or the combined cost of 7? My opponent is using the card [Fragmentize](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bFragmentize%5d) to destroy the Filigree Familiar, but we aren't sure what the CMC is equal to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The CMC of Filigree Familiar is always 3. The only time the CMC of a card changes is if it has {X} in its mana cost and it is on the stack (in which case it is the chosen value for X, other wise X counts as 0).

> **202.3.** The converted mana cost of an object is a number equal to the total amount of mana in its mana cost, regardless of color.

Comment: The CMC of a 'card' also changes if the card starts representing a different object, as with meld (202.3c.)

Comment: Recommend expanding this answer to explain that the creature and enchant are distinct entities on the battlefield, to fully correct the misunderstanding demonstrated in the question.